# Batch looping an if statement on the same line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to loop the if exist line once so that the line will run continuously until a unused sequential number is found (it has to loop on the same line so it becomes part of the if statement). Is there a better way to achieve this ?

```
if exist "*%num%*" (set /a num+=jump)
```

update

```
@echo off
set /p usrname=enter folder name 
set /a num=100
set /a jump=10

if exist "*%num%*" (set /a num+=jump) 

MD %num%_%usrname%
```

Comment: If you need the `IF` command to continue to run until it finds a file that does not exist you will at least need another line that is a label to use with the GOTO command.

Comment: How do you exit the loop then ? Is it not cleaner to have the loop  on the same line so the if statement only runs when it num var

Comment: How do you exit the loop then ? ,  I want loop off the if statement so the if statement exit the loop if the number doesn't exist

Comment: Without us seeing the provided line in context, _i.e. a few lines either side of it_, it's almost impossible for us to make informed suggestions. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47722710/edit) with that information.

Comment: I have updated the question,  basically am trying to write a batch file to automate the process of creating mutiple folders names to our naming systems and populating them with the correct dir structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is sounds like you are attempting to do is:

```
WHILE IF NOT EXIST "*%num%*" SET /A num+=jump
```

There is no such thing. You have a very limited amount of usable commands to program with in a batch file. [Here is all the commands you can use.](https://ss64.com/nt/)

What you can do to get it onto 2 lines is this

```
@echo off
set /p usrname=enter folder name 
set /a num=100
set /a jump=10

:loop
if exist "*%num%*" (set /a num+=jump & GOTO loop)

MD %num%_%usrname%
```

And if you really want to shorten it up you can use conditional execution. When the directory already exists, increment the number and goto the loop.

```
@echo off
set /p usrname=enter folder name 
set /a num=100
set /a jump=10

:loop
MD "%num%_%usrname%" 2>nul || (set /a num+=jump & GOTO loop)
```

Comment: Thank you thats was what i was looking for ,  actual that conditional execution you wrote allows for the creation of multiple num_ variations if the folder name changes e.g..  you get two  110_(different name) for example

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
@echo off
set /p usrname=enter folder name 
set /a num=100
set /a jump=10
:test_exist
if not exist "*%num%*" goto found_one
set /a num+=jump
goto test_exist
:found_one
MD %num%_%usrname%
```

There's technically a race condition in there, but that will only matter if other people/processes are working in the folder at the same time.

Comment: thank you ben that works, the race condition will probably never come up,  in the situation am intending it for,  i was hoping to get in on one line is the no way to loop the line again ?  (just so its cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use

```
@echo off
set /p usrname=enter folder name 
set /a num=100
set /a jump=10

for /L %%a in (%num%,%jump%,2000000000) do if not exist "*%%a*" set /a num=%%a & MD %%a_%usrname%&goto done
:done
```